# How to fix my broken .NET 7.0/8.0 (SDK) install on Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core

I had until recently a .NET 7.x install on my Linux box. I was all working fine, building & running .NET (specifically C#) projects, installing dotnet tools (Husky.NET, versionize, etc.).

I decided to update to .NET 8.0 to see what all the fuzz was about, but somehow my install didn't work entirely (maybe because my distro version didn't support it and .NET 8 is still hot from the oven). After that, I carried out a bunch of erratic actions attempting to keep my previous setup.

Some of the stuff I did trying to solve the issue:

- Uninstalled .NET 8
- Manually installed .NET 8. using the `dotnet-install.sh` script
- Uninstalled .NET 8 again and then .NET 7.0 after that
- Manually removed content from any location where dotnet SDKs files are installed (`~/.dotnet`, `/usr/lib/dotnet/`, `/usr/share/dotnet`, `/usr/bin/dotnet` symlink)
- Re-installed .NET 7.0 using Microsoft package repository (I think I even tried with Ubuntu's repo packages as well)

**Here are some troubleshooting commands to gauge the current state of my config.**

```
$ whereis dotnet 
dotnet: /usr/bin/dotnet /usr/lib/dotnet /etc/dotnet /usr/share/dotnet /usr/share/man/man1/dotnet.1.gz
```

```
$ which dotnet
/usr/bin/dotnet
```

```
$ dotnet
Usage: dotnet [options]
Usage: dotnet [path-to-application]

Options:
  -h|--help         Display help.
  --info            Display .NET information.
  --list-sdks       Display the installed SDKs.
  --list-runtimes   Display the installed runtimes.

path-to-application:
  The path to an application .dll file to execute.
```

**Now comes the strange part.**

Failing to get the .NET version:

```
$ dotnet --version
The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
  * You intended to execute a .NET application:
      The application '--version' does not exist.
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      No .NET SDKs were found.

Download a .NET SDK:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/download

Learn about SDK resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found
```

Display .NET information:

```
$ dotnet --info
Host:
  Version:      7.0.14
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       808851b07a

.NET SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.14 [/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.14 [/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Other architectures found:
  None

Environment variables:
  Not set

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
```

Nothing listed for SDKs:

```
$ dotnet --list-sdks
```

I see some runtimes listed:

```
dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.14 [/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.14 [/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Building a solution/project fails with the same message as before:

```
$ dotnet build
The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
  * You intended to execute a .NET application:
      The application 'build' does not exist.
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      No .NET SDKs were found.

Download a .NET SDK:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/download

Learn about SDK resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found
```

- What am I missing here?
- Any particular detail regarding how and where are .NET SDK install files are deployed that might shed some light on this issue?
- Any other troubleshooting action that might be useful here?

Additional details:

- OS: Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS x86_64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old **"turn it off and on again"** worked in my case here. I'll explain in detail the steps I took to make it work.

**The "turning off" part:**

Uninstalled/removed .NET installed using Microsoft/Ubuntu packages:

- `sudo apt-get remove dotnet-runtime-7.0 --purge`
- `sudo apt-get remove aspnetcore-runtime-7.0 --purge`

Then, completely cleared the locations where .NET is commonly installed on Linux:

- `/usr/share/dotnet`
- `/usr/lib/dotnet` (there's a symlink on /usr/bin/dotnet related to this)
- `~/.dotnet` (old folder I had from my previous attempts)

**The "turning on" part:**

I installed .NET 7.0 and .NET 8.0 with the [dotnet-install](https://github.com/dotnet/install-scripts) scripts for a manual install (no Microsoft or Ubuntu packages this time).

I specifically set the install location to `~/.dotnet` not to lose it in the event of a re-install:

```bash
./dotnet-install.sh --version 8.0.100 --install-dir ~/.dotnet
```

Here's the outline of the `~/.dotnet` folder after the install finished:

```
.
...
├── corefx
├── dotnet
├── host
├── LICENSE.txt
├── MachineId.v1.dotnetUserLevelCache
├── metadata
├── packs
├── sdk
├── sdk-advertising
├── sdk-manifests
├── shared
├── TelemetryStorageService
├── templates
└── ThirdPartyNotices.txt
```

Additionally, set the `$DOTNET_ROOT` environment variable to the folder containing the .NET SDK installation (in this case the `~/.dotnet` folder).

Finally, dotnet tools and commands like `dotnet --version`, `dotnet --list-sdks`, `dotnet --info` and `dotnet build` are working flawlessly again.